# how to follow after window popup when the url has changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a window.open popup in js
now i what in my nuxtjs app (vuejs)
follow after the url of that popup
and when i get a param ?code= in the url
get the data from this url to my data "info"

The backend and the frontend is on other servers

I am using laravel socialite in backend and i am trying to make this social api request

```
              <template>
                <section class="container">
              <a  @click.stop="socialLogin()">google</a>
              {{ info }}
                </section>
              </template>

              <script>


              export default {
                data(){
                  return{
                    info: {},
                  }
                },
                methods: {  
                async socialLogin(){
                    await this.$axios.$get(`http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/google`)
                        .then((response) => {
                          if(response.redirectUrl){


                            const newWindow = openWindow(response.redirectUrl)
                            console.log(newWindow);


                          }
                          //console.log(response)
                          })
                    },


                  },

              }

              function openWindow (url, title, options = {}) {
                if (typeof url === 'object') {
                  options = url
                  url = ''
                }
                options = { url, title, width: 600, height: 720, ...options }
                const dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft !== undefined ? window.screenLeft : window.screen.left
                const dualScreenTop = window.screenTop !== undefined ? window.screenTop : window.screen.top
                const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.screen.width
                const height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.screen.height
                options.left = ((width / 2) - (options.width / 2)) + dualScreenLeft
                options.top = ((height / 2) - (options.height / 2)) + dualScreenTop
                const optionsStr = Object.keys(options).reduce((acc, key) => {
                  acc.push(`${key}=${options[key]}`)
                  return acc
                }, []).join(',')
                const newWindow = window.open(url, title, optionsStr)
                if (window.focus) {
                  newWindow.focus()
                }
                return newWindow
              }

              </script>

              <style>

              </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right your function `openWindow`should be a method which you can call in your `socialLogin` with `this.openWindow(...)` like:

```
if(response.redirectUrl){
  const newWindow = this.openWindow(response.redirectUrl)
  console.log(newWindow);
}
```

Then in your new method `openWindow` you can easily set your info with:

`this.info = url`.